# Authenticate User In Django via Flutter App and JSON Web Token

Tags: api, authentication, flutter, django-rest-framework, jwt

How do I Authenticate User in Django-Rest-Framework via my Flutter App?
I did this in Postman before and this is how I did it:

1. Post Request to (IP:8000/get-token/) > Returns JSON Web Token
2. Get Request with Bearer Token to (IP:8000/database/exercises/) > Returns JSON file! - Note that if I don't use the token I will get nothing in return!

How do I replicate this via a Flutter http.post Request?

This is how I will do the signup process (In this case not with the token):

```
//text-field controllers
TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

//post request
postRequest() async {
String _url = "IP:8000/get-token/";
var response = await http.post(
  Uri.encodeFull(_url),
  headers: { "Accept" : "application/json"},
  body: {
    "username": "${usernameController.text}",
    "password": "${passwordController.text}",
  },
  encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8"),
);

//Name TextField (Simplified Code)
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2, top: 25),
    child: TextField(
    controller: nameController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: "Name..."             
      ))
)

//Password TextField (Simplified Code)
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2, top: 25),
    child: TextField(
    controller: passwordController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: "Password..."             
      ))
)

//Simplified but you get what I mean
Inkwell(
  child: Container()
  onTap() 
  {
    postRequest(),
    Navigator.push(Into-App)
  }
)
```

My question is: How do I take the response from this request? (if username and password match the database).

And how do I use the token I get in response to do future request to get data inside the app?

The Django-Backend:

```
#urls
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('database/', include('PlanThatWorkout.urls')),
    path('get-token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view()),
    path('refresh-token/', TokenRefreshView.as_view())
]

#settings
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES' : ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',),
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' : ('rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',),
}
```

Comment: When the server returns the token, you would keep it in localStorage on the client. Then, in subsequent requests you would include that localStorage object in your http request headers. Note that in production you should only do this in HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the token by decoding your response with [dart:convert](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.1/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html).

```
import 'dart:convert';
Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(reponse);
final jwt = data['jwt-key'];
```

To persist your data, you can save this on disk writing in file with [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<File> write(String jwt) async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final path = directory.path;
    final file = File('$path/jwt.txt');
    return file.writeAsString('$jwt');
}

Future<String> read() async {
    try { in a file or using 
      final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final path = directory.path;
      final file = File('$path/jwt.txt');
      String contents = await file.readAsString();
      return contents;
    } catch (e) {
      return '';
    }
  }
```

or using [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences).

Comment: response can't be assigned to parameter of type string

Comment: I Fixed everything with login, how do I make a post request with the token?

Comment: just add your token to authentication headers.
 `headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Authentication": "Bearer $token"
    }`